# Using Simple jQuery click() events in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript

I've been able to get jQuery to load and work for some basic things such as:

```
(function ($) {
  console.log('jquery called');

  $(document).click(function() {
    var h1 = $('h1').text();
    console.log(h1);
  });
}(jQuery));
```

However, when I try to do the following, nothing happens.

```
(function ($) {
  $("h1").click(function() {
    alert('clicked!');
  });
}(jQuery));
```

I'm wondering if this has something to do with when the .js file gets called. I suspect that the document element already exists, so having a click event on it is no problem. However, I think that the h1 elements don't exist by the time the click event is loaded. I've tried the .bind() and .on() functions as well, with no luck.

Any ideas?

I call my .js file from my theme's info file, not sure if that matters.

Comment: have you tried it in  $(document).ready() function?

Comment: Yeah, I tried putting the test alert() in the $(document).ready() function, but it still didn't work.

Comment: are there any errors in the console.log?

Comment: Nope, no errors in the console.log.

Answer (score 2):

```
(function ($) {
// To understand behaviors, see https://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors
Drupal.behaviors.ss2 = {
  attach: function(context, settings) {

  $("h1").click(function() {
    alert('clicked!');
  });
}}

})(jQuery);
```

be careful with braces at the end, and rename ss2 as you want, it's just for example...

Comment: I had tried getting it to work using behaviors, but that was a dead-end for me as well.

Comment: No try understand, just use as it is shown.

Comment: This gets my vote. Behaviors are the Drupal way; they are called after the DOM is created, so there isn't any problem with the code trying to access an HTML element before it is created. Plus, they are a must in the serious Drupal programming.

Answer (score -1):

So figured out that having your jQuery called in the footer after all the dom elements load works much better for things like click events. Here is how I got it to work:

- Open your theme's **template.php** file
- In the **ThemeName_preprocess_html(&$variables)** function add the
  following:

> ```
>     drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', '**ThemeName**') . '/js/**FileName**.js', array( 
>       'scope' => 'footer', 
>       'weight' => '15' 
>     ));
> ```

- Have your **FileName**.js file look something like this:

> (function ($) {
>   //insert your jquery here
>   $('h1').click(function() {
>       $(this).hide('slow');
>       console.log('h1 clicked!');
>   }); 
>   }(jQuery));

Comment: This show that you have something broken on the site, in future it will raise new problem, resolve first your issue...